# Jekyll converts <i> tags to <em> tags

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

We are converting an existing static site to Jekyll. We are using  tags to show Font Awesome Icons, as below

```
<a class="box-icon-title margin-bottom-20" href="#">
<i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>
```

However, jekyll converts all these  tags to  tags as below

```
<a class="box-icon-title margin-bottom-20" href="#"> 
<em class="fa fa-picture-o"></em>
```

Any idea how to prevent Jekyll from converting  tags to  tags

Comment: Are you using the HTML italics in an .md file perhaps? Or is this in a layout? Can you elaborate on WHERE this happens (which file)?

Comment: I think the kramdown is the source of this problem not Jekyll.

Answer (score 4):

Jekyll does not convert `<i>` tags to `<em>` tags out-of-the-box.
Likely to be a result of some plugins you're using.

Please post the contents of your `Gemfile`, `_config.yml` and `_plugins` directory if available.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Jekyll converts `<i>` tags but if does, its better not to modify the Jekyll. Instead I suggest a simple jquery code to convert `<em>` back to `<i>` again where maitaining all attributes:

```
$(document).on("ready",function(){
    $('em.fa').replaceWith(function(){
       $iTag = $("<i>", {html: $(this).html()});
       $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attribute){
            $iTag.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
      });
      return $iTag;
    })
})
```

**Note:** If `$(document).on("ready")` did'nt work try `$(window).on("load")`

**Note:** If Jekyll has a callback function after finishing, the best way would be to call the above function as callback of Jekyll not on DOM ready.

Comment: I think that this is not really an elegant solution. I gave you an upvote for the clear answer though. It might help somebody...